# C#: take control over file transfers* 

Tags: c#, pinvoke, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I'd like to have a program that runs in the background, listens for any file transfers, and then cancels explorer's file transfer mechanism, and starts it's own.

How do I do this?  Is there some dll that I can pinvoke?

Why?

- To filter files of certain types along the way. (automatically, or with a prompt.)
- A "no to all" duplicate transfers option.
- Logging.
- To not have to start the program up every time I want to transfer files.
- To further understand what's going on under the hood.
- To not rely on third party programs.
- Any additional features I think of in the future.

*
By file transfers I mean moving/copying files/folders via drag and drop, but I am only concerned with file transfers from disk to disk, not from the internet.

Comment: Shift+No is usually the same as No To All, just so you know ;)

Comment: Do you mean Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer?

Comment: @minitech:  great, thanks.
@Robert Harvey: windows explorer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144063(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Robert: I think that ought to be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @sehe: It's not an answer, only a link to another resource. The OP will have to research it and figure out if that's what he needs.

Comment: A good one, that answers the question :)

Comment: unfortunately not completely: that ought to work for folders and printers

Comment: @Robert: distributing the reputation wealth are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define "file transfer".

Do you want to sniff for ftp, http requests? Explorer copies as well? Local only or on the network?

I think this is bound to get brittle. Your best bet would be if explorer let's you hook into file copy operations via a [shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468984%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I'm not sure whether it can be done.

See [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx) for a starting point.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144063(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thx Robert, that is elegant of you to add

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it's bound to get brittle" or why "this is going to finish bad"?

Comment: You are trying to modify the OS. This will only work if the OS was designed to let you do that. The closest you can come is hooking Explorer; still that won't get you `control over file transfers` in general, since there will be transfers that won't trigger the hook. Moreover, there will be border cases in which the hook doesn't do what you want or interferes badly with other software (say, when your virus scanner wants to quarantaine a file, you don't want the hook to trigger). **In short**: if this is a security critical part, don't do it. Is it convenience, go for the `ICopyHook` option

Answer (score 3):

Before I start: This is going to finish bad, but nevertheless:

For Vista/7:

You need to Hook ([Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking))

To [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then change what you need from there.

This won't work on XP however, and is probably so fragile that will work on some PCs and not on others because there are millions of ways to do the same thing on windows from the API perspective.

Comment: +1 Hear hear. This is the second day in a row where I've seen an answer of yours with a prophetically `true` quality to it -- yet I can't prove it ([see here for the other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899274/shuffle-list-with-some-conditions/5904381#5904381))

Comment: you know I actually coded that thingy? I have it at work, the most complex part was creating the recursion on the insertion in the graph. I think there still is a bug somewhere. Monday I'll post it there if I dont forget.

Comment: I like fiddling with algoritms more than properly coding, just for the fun of proving my assumptions correct. Like this two hour time waste here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909031/fast-2d-illumination-algorithm/5915431#5915431